# Datepicker input field: selected date is displayed despite value empty

Tags: javascript, html, webflow

I have a datepicker which the user can select a date from. When a date is selected, the input field is being filled with the right value, and it is displayed.

However, then submitting the form, the field posts empty data for that field, like it is only being displayed in the input field but it has no value.

I know it's really hard to describe this issue, so I'm attaching some images.

Here is the js code behind the datepicker itself:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="datepickerFrom"]').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
        });
        // Available date placeholders:
        // Year: yyyy
        // Month: mm
        // Day: dd
        if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
            $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').attr('readonly', 'readonly')
        }
    });

</script>
```

[image: Empty input field for datepicker]

[image: The date is selected and the input field shows the selected date]

[image: Empty value even if the field displayes a value]

Comment: Attach some code

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion, I'm using webflow, so I'm not sure how much it can help